# Trouble handling JavaScript File Objects - How To Pass Them Onto CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I'm having trouble handling JS file objects. I'm using the drag and drop modal file upload plugin which can be found here: http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Drag-Drop-File-Upload-Dialog-with-jQuery-Bootstrap.html

Here is my specific code that handles the file upload:

```
$.FileDialog({

            // MIME type of accepted files, e. g. image/jpeg
            accept: "*",

            // cancel button
            cancelButton: "Close",

            // drop zone message
            dragMessage: "Drop files here",

            // the height of drop zone in pixels
            dropheight: 400,

            // error message
            errorMessage: "An error occured while loading file",

            // whether it is possible to choose multiple files or not.
            multiple: true,

            // OK button
            okButton: "OK",

            // file reading mode.
            // BinaryString, Text, DataURL, ArrayBuffer
            readAs: "DataURL",

            // remove message
            removeMessage: "Remove&nbsp;file",

            // file dialog title
            title: "Load file(s)"

            });
        // handle files choice when done
        }).on('files.bs.filedialog', function(ev) {
          var files_list = ev.files;
          // DO SOMETHING
          alert(files_list[0].content);
        }).on('cancel.bs.filedialog', function(ev) {
          // DO SOMETHING
          // handle dialog cancelling       
        });
```

As you can see, I've tried to make an alert so that I could see whether any file was being uploaded, but nothing shows up. What I'm wondering is whether this script is actually working. I'm slightly lost on how to debug it. And, if it is. What would be my next step to getting the file data to codeigniter so that I can upload it to my server?

Thanks for any help here!

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome, IE, or Firefox and switch to the **console** tab to see if you are getting any errors.

Comment: It was the first thing I checked. Nothing there.